# How does a domain registrar forward emails from non existent account

Tags: email, domain-registration, domain-registrar, email-address, email-accounts

I've registered a domain in a domain registrar, and in one of its' upgrades it includes an email address for the domain (for example `info@example.com` if I registered the domain `example.com`), for a monthly fee.

However, even without upgrading to that plan, the registrar includes the option to forward emails to my personal email address.
For example, every email sent to `info@example.com` will be received in my own personal `example@gmail.com` inbox. It automatically appends the appropriate MX records to the DNS table for the domain.

How is that possible, if I haven't created the mail address for `info@example.com`?
What makes it able to receive and forward emails, but not send ones from that address (or maybe there is a way to do that, and the email address upgrade includes different perks)?

Comment: I'm not sure what magic you think happens when you "create a mail address," but it sounds like they just do that for you because they are controlling the MX records and mail server for the domain.  There is nothing that prevents you (or anybody else) from sending emails from that address. There is very little authentication on sent emails.   Is there something that you would expect to prevent your domain registrar from acting as your email host?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I was under the impression that there was. That your domain and email address hosting were tied together. I understand now that this is not the case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying a bit -

A typical (Linux based, like Postfix) mail server is comprised of multiple subprograms (think modules) which are chained together. Included in this are modules for receiving email, classifying it as spam, **routing the email on to a destination** and delivering it.

The module for routing mail can as easily route the mail to a new address as it can deliver it to a mailbox - and this is the functionality being engaged.  It is significantly "lighter weight" to do this as you don't need to manage storage or provide a pop/IMAP/webmail interface.

Save for records in DNS, email is almost entirely divorces from web hosting and other services for your domain.